# Python Multiprocessing Pickling Confusion in Classes

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have been told that pickling class methods for multiprocessing are not possible with Processes. For some reason though, this code works. I have tried to complete this same task in other applications and my results have been inconsistent. What can I do for this feature to consistently work?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class test():
  def run(self):
    print("HI")

  def p(self):
    p = Process(target=self.run)
    p.start()


a = test()
a.p()
```

I have tried utilizing this functionality with python3 and python and it has worked and not worked for both versions. How do I ensure this works?

Comment: What do you mesn with 'worked and not worked'? What did you see? This code would fail on Windows.

Comment: I tried both python3 and python and it worked and didn't work for both. Meaning using either version did not make a difference. Why would it not work on windows? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I still don' t get what "it worked and didn't work" mean. It worked once and stopped worked the next time? How did it fail? Did it print anything?  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70580915/17457042) and don't forget to call ` join`

Answer (score 0):

When starting a new process, Windows and Mac *Spawn* the process which requires objects to be pickled. On Linux however, the process is *Forked* which inherits memory from the parent process. If a class contains non-pickle-able objects and you want to run a class method on a separate process, you must use Linux.