# Runtime error when trying to spawn multiple processes (image detection and print to terminal)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was following [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/a-beginners-guide-to-multi-processing-in-python/) guide to try and see if I could get a simple multiprocessing script to run. It's been discussed in other questions that I **need** to use multiprocessing for what I'm trying to achieve.

For the sake of following the beginner guide, I wrote two functions.

```
import pyautogui as py
import multiprocessing

def print_i():
    for i in range(0, 21):
        print(i)
        sleep(0.1)

image = r'C:\Users\image.jpg'

def closeWindow():
    while True:
        found = py.locateCenterOnScreen(image)
            if found != None:
            py.click(1797, 134)
```

`print_i` prints out the numbers 0-20 and `closeWindow` checks if a particular window is open then clicks to close it if it finds it, both work individually.

In following the guide I've imported `multiprocessing` and done the following:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target= print_i)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target= closeWindow)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

However, I immediately get following error twice:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993339/issue-with-spawning-multiple-processes) stack explains that the multiprocessing module should take care of these cases and detect that you are trying to start new processes even before the target was run.

In reading the error in mentions not using `fork` to start a child process, I didn't think I had a child process, does anything after your first process count as a child process when multiprocessing? If yes, how can I output the numbers 0-20 with one process while running the image detection at the same time?

Comment: Do you **have** to use multiprocessing or are you open to alternative libraries like `threading`?

Comment: In my main script I run a lot of image detection and GUI interactions, what I'm trying to do is run a second script that also does GUI interactions on the same screen. Script one is sequential, script two is to deal with random issues (mostly closing rogue windows  I can't predict in script one). So long as both can run together I don't mind! Someone else just said *you need to use multiprocessing for this*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to schedule or run tasks continuously. Here are a few examples:

Using Threading:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def run_close_window_task():
    while True:
        print("Hello, close window task is running!")
        sleep(2)

t = Thread(name='backgroundtask', target=run_close_window_task)
t.start()

print("Now we are doing other stuff, while the other task is running...")
```

NOTE: You have to kill the Python process via task manager in Windows to stop it.

Result:

```
Hello, close window task is running!
Now we are doing other stuff, while the other task is running...
Hello, close window task is running!
Hello, close window task is running!
Hello, close window task is running!
...
```

Using Asyncio:

```
from asyncio import sleep, run, create_task, gather

async def run_close_window_task():
    while True:
        print("Hello, close window task is running!")
        await sleep(2)

async def print_i():
    while True:
        for i in range(0, 21):
            print(f"Printing i: {str(i)}")
            await sleep(0.2)

async def main():
    tasks = [create_task(run_close_window_task()), create_task(print_i())]
    await gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Result:

```
Hello, close window task is running!
Printing i: 0
Printing i: 1
Printing i: 2
Printing i: 3
Printing i: 4
Printing i: 5
Printing i: 6
Printing i: 7
Printing i: 8
Printing i: 9
Hello, close window task is running!
Printing i: 10
Printing i: 11
Printing i: 12
Printing i: 13
Printing i: 14
Printing i: 15
Printing i: 16
Printing i: 17
Printing i: 18
Printing i: 19
...
```

Comment: Threading worked perfectly. Thank you!