# How do I run parallel threads/processes in a single test in Appium (Python)?

Tags: python, appium

In Appium (using Python) I want to send the app to the background, do some work while the app is in background (that would send a push notification to the app), and then return to the app.

I tried to do it with threads (`threading.Thread` Python class), but it wouldn't do it in parallel - the app would sit in background, and after that was done, the second thread would start.

Then I tried it with `multiprocessing.Process`, but I'm getting `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'PoolManager.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'`

How should I go about this?

These are the parts of the code I have now (as I understand, the functions that should be parallelized need to be outside of the class):

```
def send_app_to_background(app_driver, seconds=10):
    app_driver.background_app(seconds)

def asdf_verify_user(page:OnboardingPage, passenger_email):
    mailer = MyMailer(passenger_email, page.settings)
    verification_url = mailer.get_verification_url()
    page.open_verification_url(verification_url)
```

And this is how it's called from inside the test class:

```
class TestMails(kh.BasicTest):
    def test_registration_mails(self):
        ........
        jobs = []
        process1 = Process(target=send_app_to_background, args=(self.app_driver, 20))
        process2 = Process(target=verify_user, args=(page, passenger_email))
        jobs.append(process1)
        jobs.append(process2)
        for j in jobs:
            j.start()
        
        for j in jobs:
            j.join()
```

Comment: Use a thread to run your function. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601983/runtime-error-when-trying-to-spawn-multiple-processes-image-detection-and-print/71602709#71602709

Comment: I tried it with asyncio. Those functions stayed the same (except for the 'async' keyword in front), and I created another function to call them:
async def asdf(app_driver, page:OnboardingPage, passenger_email):
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(send_app_to_background(app_driver, 20))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(verify_user(page, passenger_email))
    await task1
    await task2
and then I call that from the test like asyncio.run(asdf(self.app_driver, page, passenger_email))
But it's still sequential......

Comment: I think the problem is that `background_app(seconds)`, which is a function of the Appium object, is not async.. I tried playing with two async functions that use `time.sleep()` instead of `await asyncio.sleep()`, and they behave exactly as my functions above....

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently, it's not possible to do it like this. Appium's `background_app()` function is locking the other threads. My solution was to use  `close_app()` and `launch_app()` instead.